# issue with ggplot2/geom_line - subjets datasets plotted erroneously jointly

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have an issue with the follwoing dataframe although I followed standard examples for line plots.
As shown in the plot, two of the three subjects dummy time courses are plotted jointly instead of being plotted separately

```
library(tidyverse)

blub <- structure(list(time = seq(0,10,by=1), 
                     sub1 = seq(10,20,by=1), 
                     sub2 = seq(20,30,by=1), 
                     sub3 = seq(30,40,by=1)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
                class = "data.frame")

bluba <- gather(data = blub, key=subjects, value=value, 2:ncol(blub))

basic <- c("N","P","P")
statusArray <- rep(basic,each=11)

bluba$status <- statusArray

print(ggplot(data=bluba, 
             aes(x=time,y=value, color=status)) +
             geom_line())
```

[image: I extected three instead of two time series, each line for my three subjects]

Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `group` to `aes` to specify the connection of line

```
print(ggplot(data=bluba, 
             aes(x=time,y=value, color=status, group = subjects)) +
        geom_line())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `linetype = subjects`

```
   bluba %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=time,y=value, color=status, linetype=subjects)) +
      geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: interesting, but with >100 subjects the solution by www works better